# Cannot await 'Model.PersonalInfo'

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I have the following method in a DesignDataService class

```
public async Task<T> GetData<T>(T dataObject)
{
    var typeName = typeof(T).Name;    
    switch (typeName)
    {
        case "PersonalInfo":
            var person =  new PersonalInfo
                     {
                     FirstName = "Mickey",
                     LastName = "Mouse" ,
                     Adres = new Address{Country="DLRP"} ,
                };
        return await person;

    }   // end Switch

}   // GetData<T>
```

How can I return a new PersonalInfo class from the DataService?

For now I get the error **Cannot await 'Model.PersonalInfo'**

Even when I change the return statement as follows *return await person as Task;*
 the error stays the same

Comment: Why do you need to await?, you have already created the object so I see no reason to run is asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this function returns a `Task`, there is no requirement to use the `async` keyword.

Here, you can simply use [Task.FromResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx)

```
public Task<T> GetData<T>(T dataObject) where T : MyKnownBaseObject
{
    var typeName = typeof(T).Name;    
    switch (typeName)
    {
        case "PersonalInfo":
            var person =  new PersonalInfo
                     {
                     FirstName = "Mickey",
                     LastName = "Mouse" ,
                     Adres = new Address{Country="DLRP"} ,
                };
            return Task.FromResult<T>(person);
            break;
        default:
               return Task.FromResult<T>(default(T));

    }   // end Switch

}   // GetData<T>
```

This will not delegate work to another thread. This technique works if you have a small amount of work that doesn't lend itself to parralellism, yet you must still force the method to return a task to be compatible with other methods.

Comment: +1. @Gooftroop, it's common for a design-time type or testing stub to use this approach (`Task.FromResult` with a *non*-`async` implementation).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two things. You annotate a method with `async` to instruct to compiler that you would like to be able to `await` an asynchronous operation (in a Task).

On the other hand, the return value is a `Task`. You can mix both, but in your case (`async Task<T>`) it means that you are returning an asynchronous promise of an operation but you also wait for the result of one within the method, which is assuredly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the async and the error is gone. Hopefully it will work with live data also. But that's for to morrow.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If creation of `PersonalInfo` is expected to take a long time you will want to add the creation of the object into a Task and await on that.

You don't seem to have a type restriction on your method so to return `PersonalInfo` you will have to cast as `T` from `object`.

Example:

```
    public async Task<T> GetData<T>(T dataObject)
    {
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;
        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "PersonalInfo":
                return await Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return (T)(object)new PersonalInfo
                    {
                        FirstName = "Mickey",
                        LastName = "Mouse",
                        Adres = new Address { Country = "DLRP" },
                    };
                });
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to create another task and await it if the method is already async and returning task, is there?

Comment: Just did a test. The inner task is not required.. you can simply return the new personal info object.

Comment: There is no need to await at all, My assumtion is that this is a demo and creation of `PersonalInfo` requires Database or WebService calls, otherwise I have no idea why the async is required as the object is already created

Comment: Even so - pretend the PersonalInfo object's constructor takes 20 seconds. You still dont need to initialize an inner task. because the void is async the entire thing is wrapped in a task, so simply returning the personalinfo object would be sufficient - and then you can wait upon the task returned by the method.

Comment: @caesay, Good to know, I just finished my .NET4.5 exam (and passed) but I guess I still dont understand some aspects of this yet. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: @caesay: You don't expect anyone to take you seriously when you say "the void" instead of "the function is `async`", do you?

Comment: @BenVoigt: My bad, I used the incorrect term but the point is still valid.